# Predicate for STL algorithms

Tags: c++

I have the following question:

```
find_if(s.begin(), s.end(), isalpha);
```

s is a library string. when I try to use isalpha (in "cctype" header), it saids, "type doesn't match". The problem is that isalpha takes a int and return a int: int isalpha(int)

I solved it by declaring another function:

```
bool IsAlpha(char c) {
  return isalpha(c);
}
```

However, is there any better way to do this? I would prefer better code clarity & simplicity, without declaring this "wrapper" function.

Thanks!

Comment: What i'm doing wrong? http://liveworkspace.org/code/28S1na$0

Comment: Alan, can you quote the exact compiler error and the exact code for which you are getting it? Until than, -1.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there was at least one compiler that wanted you to cast it: `(int(*)(int))isalpha`

Comment: @chris: Well, yes. If the function is overloaded by the implementation, it has to be cast like this. That's why I want to see the exact compiler diagnostics and not just "something about type mismatch".

Comment: There is also huge difference between trying to use `isalpha` from standard C library and `std::isalpha` from standard C++ library (the later is tempaltes and has 2 arguments, so it won't work that easily).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose the 'proper' C++ way is to use the `isalpha` defined in locale:

```
std::find_if(
    s.begin(), 
    s.end(), 
    [](char c) { return std::isalpha(c, std::locale()); }
);
```

A little verbose maybe.

Comment: Might be a bit verbose, but you can always save the lambda for later reuse, or write a wrapper.

Comment: It might be worth to define the polymorphic functor (`struct isalpha_functor { template <typename CharT> bool operator()(CharT c) { return std::isalpha(c, std::locale()); }};`) as it would be usable with all types of chars (`char`, `wchar_t`, `char16_t` and `char32_t`).

Answer (score 1):

Only way, that I can imagine is, that you use `using namespace std`, since you wrote `find_if`, not `std::find_if` and in this case you has following error
[Live example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/28S1na%245). You shouln't write wrapper, you can simply use `::isalpha` [Live example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/28S1na%246) or you can bind second par to default locale, like [here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/28S1na%24)

Comment: All links broken.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution looks fine to me. Except that it has a very common bug

```
bool IsAlpha(char c) {
  return isalpha(c);
}
```

should be

```
bool IsAlpha(char c) {
  return isalpha((unsigned char)c);
}
```

isalpha is only defined for unsigned char values (which are normally 0 to 255) and EOF (which is normally -1). Strictly speaking passing any other negative value to isalpha is undefined. What you will find in practice however is that (assuming your char type is signed) if you give your routine the character with the code 255, you will end up passing the value of -1 to isalpha which will always return false.

Comment: Have you seen ForEveR's comment on the question? If you did, you'd know the solution is wrong, because the problem does not exist in the first place.

Comment: What's all this about?  isalpha takes an `int`, not an `unsigned char`. And it works perfectly fine when passed a `char` which is implicitly convertible to `int`.

Comment: @JanHudec I am assuming the OP isn't mistaken when he says he has a compiler error.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I think I explained it well enough in the answer. A negative char value will be converted to a negative int value, and that is undefined for isalpha. Even experienced programmers are sometimes unaware of this issue with isalpha.

Comment: Since OP didn't quote the exact compiler error, it is far more probable they incorrectly interpreted their actual error than they have a compiler error.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Of course compiler writers have anticipated that this mistake happens and they do write isalpha to work in the way people expect. However what that cannot do anything about is `char c = 255; isalpha(c)` because this cannot be distinguished from EOF by isalpha.

Comment: Hm, I only have C++ standard lying around and `std::isalpha` is completely different (it is template, for type of character and has second argument, the locale).

Comment: My answer is assuming the traditional C routine of course. Didn't know about any template.

Comment: By the way, these days narrow strings are usually utf-8 if they are not ascii, so 128-255 are not characters at all anyway.

Answer (score 0):

How about using functors?

```
    struct IsAlpha {
      bool operator() (char c) const { return /* isAlpha logic here */; }         
    };
    //... 
    find_if(begin, end, IsAlpha());
```

Have a look at advantages of using functors with stl algorithms [here](http://cs.ioc.ee/yik/schools/sum2006/generic_programming/functors.html)

Comment: Except in this case I don't see any advantage at all.

Comment: @Jan, to quote a few advantages, functors can be polymorphic, compilers may inline functors (not possible using a function), acts as convenient template arguments, the list goes on...

Comment: But in _this_ case they are not necessary. Though, actually a _polymorphic_ template would be nice here, since `std::isalpha` is a template.

Comment: Why not? in this case the functor can be inlined by the compiler giving a performance boost. Again this can be categorized as micro-optimization. Quite arguable.